# how to convert this into a typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsx

How to make this jsx in typescript. In javascript, it looks like this. But in typescript, I don't know how to achieve this exact code!

```
const Users = ({details,deleteUser}) => {
    return (
        <>
            <div>
            {details.map(detail => (
                <tr key={detail.del}>
                    <td>{detail.del}</td>
                    <td>{detail.name}</td>
                    <td>{detail.email}</td>
                    <td>{detail.pass}</td>
                    <td>{detail.contact}</td>
                    <td className='delete-btn' onClick={() => deleteUser(detail.del)}>
                        Delete
                    </td>
                </tr>
            ))}
            </div>
        </>
    )}
```

Comment: Javascript is always valid Typescript. You might want to use string interpolation that Javascript provides though, replacing `{detail.del}` with `${detail.del}` for example. I think you might want to do a little more research before asking questions like this since we expect a working piece of code or a specific bug to work with. Also, I think the question could use a little more explanation.

Comment: @Randy isn't OP's code JSX?

Answer (score 1):

As first you should define your props type:

```js
type User = {
  del: string;
  name: string;
  email: string;
  pass: string;
  contact: string;
};
type UsersProps = {
  details: User[];
  deleteUser: (del: string) => void;
};
```

After this you should apply the type to the component props:

```js
const Users = (props: UsersProps) => {
    const {details,deleteUser} = props;
    return (
        <>
            <div>
            {details.map(detail => (
                <tr key={detail.del}>
                    <td>{detail.del}</td>
                    <td>{detail.name}</td>
                    <td>{detail.email}</td>
                    <td>{detail.pass}</td>
                    <td>{detail.contact}</td>
                    <td className='delete-btn' onClick={() => deleteUser(detail.del)}>
                        Delete
                    </td>
                </tr>
            ))}
            </div>
        </>
    )
};
```

In this way typescript will show you any typo, for example if you write `detail.mail` instead of `detail.email` ts will highlight it for you.

Comment: but im passing the props from another component means then how could i achieve

Comment: You can simply use the component as usual: `<Users details={details} deleteUser={deleteUser} />`

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need the interface of the User in typescript.

```
export default interface IUser {
   id: number,
   name: string,
   image: string,
   ...others
}
```

Then you need to define the passed parameters it should look like the User interface. So the code will be.

```
{details<IUser[]>.map(detail => (
                <tr key={detail.del}>
                    <td>{detail.del}</td>
                    <td>{detail.name}</td>
                    <td>{detail.email}</td>
                    <td>{detail.pass}</td>
                    <td>{detail.contact}</td>
                </tr>
            ))}
```